# Overloading multiplication operator fails

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a RGB Class for a AVR project.
But when i try to use it, it fails at some operators.

```
Error   415 no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'const float' and 'RGB')    ...\Animation\Wall\Wall.cpp 321 18  Cube
```

Here is how it looks:

```
class RGB
{
//variables
public:
    uint8_t r, g, b;
//functions
public:
    RGB();
    //assignment
    RGB &operator=( const RGB &other );

    RGB &operator+(const RGB &other);

    RGB &operator* (const uint8_t &other);
    RGB &operator* (const float &other);
//some more operators here
}; //RGB
```

And the implementation:

```
RGB::RGB(): r(0), g(0), b(0)
{
}

RGB &RGB::operator=( const RGB &other)
{
    if(this != &other) //no self assignment
    {
        r = other.r;
        g = other.g;
        b = other.g;
    }
    //per convention return "yourself"
    return *this;
}

RGB &RGB::operator+(const RGB &other)
{
    r += other.r;
    r %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    g += other.g;
    g %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    b += other.b;
    b %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    //per convention return "yourself"
    return *this;
}

RGB &RGB::operator*(RGB rgb, const uint8_t &i)
{
    rgb.r *= i;
    rgb.r %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.g *= i;
    rgb.g %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.b *= i;
    rgb.b %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    //per convention return "yourself"
    return *this;
}

RGB &RGB::operator*( const float &f, RGB rgb)
{
    rgb.r *= f;
    rgb.r %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.g *= f;
    rgb.g %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.b *= f;
    rgb.b %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    return rgb;
}

RGB &RGB::operator*(const uint8_t &i, RGB rgb)
{
    rgb.r *= i;
    rgb.r %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.g *= i;
    rgb.g %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.b *= i;
    rgb.b %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    //per convention return "yourself"
    return rgb;
}

RGB &RGB::operator*(RGB rgb, const float &f)
{
    rgb.r *= f;
    rgb.r %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.g *= f;
    rgb.g %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.b *= f;
    rgb.b %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    return rgb;
}
```

Whan i am trying todo is (Line 321 from the Error):

```
RGB newColor;
newColor = v * m_color + (1 - v) * m_targetColor;
```

And V is some value `[0,1]`.
What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your member operator

```
RGB &operator* (const float &other);
```

is equivalent to the non-member operator:

```
RGB& operator* (RGB, float);
```

This handles the left-hand multiplication: `RGB() * float()`. You need to add a second, non-member `operator*` to handle the right-hand multiplication:

```
RGB operator*(float, const RGB& );
```

Note that the `operator*` should return an `RGB`, not an `RGB&` as you are currently returning a reference to a temporary `RGB`.

Comment: The problem is a bit different. He already defined the operator which handled the right-hand multiplication, but unfortunately he made it a member function.

Comment: With the same explanation, an other solution is to change `newColor = v * m_color + (1 - v) * m_targetColor;` in `newColor = m_color * v + m_targetColor * (v - 1);`

Comment: Thanks. Added the righthand operator and also friend it. Let me guess, the same thing need to be done for the devision operator right?

Answer (score 1):

Your binary operator `*` operator overload which takes a rhs value of type RGB should be a non member function as, you have overloaded the operator for RGB, but that method is not defined for float

Convert

```
RGB &RGB::operator*( const float &f, RGB rgb)
{
    rgb.r *= f;
    rgb.r %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.g *= f;
    rgb.g %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    rgb.b *= f;
    rgb.b %= MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    return rgb;
}
```

To a non member function

```
RGB operator*( const float &f,const  RGB& rgb)
{
    RGB _rgb = rgb;
    _rgb = _rgb * f;
    return _rgb;
}
```

and make the above as friend

**Note**

A better design is to only overload the unary operator for your class and make all binary operators as non member.

```
RGB& RGB::operator*( const float &f)
{
    r = (r * f) % MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    g = (g * f) % MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    b = (b * f) % MAX_COLOR_RGB;
    return *this;
}

RGB operator*( const float &f,const RGB& rgb)
{
    RGB _rgb = rgb;
    _rgb = _rgb * f;
    return _rgb;
}

RGB operator*( const RGB& rgb, const float &f)
{
    RGB _rgb = rgb;
    _rgb = _rgb * f;
    return _rgb;
}
```

Comment: _"Your binary operator * operator overload which takes a rvalue of type RGB"_ An rvalue? Really?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: Please scroll down the OPs implementation. You can see it.

Comment: I don't think "rvalue" means what you think it means.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: It true sense it would mean different, though I meant some thing else. Reedited the answer.